# Samsung's multi window support - Screen size

Tags: android, size, samsung-mobile, multi-window

I'm currently developping my app to be compatible with the samsung multi window feature introduced with the galaxy note 2 and soon the galaxy s3. If you don't know what I'm talking about :
[image]
<sub>(source: [androidheadlines.com](http://androidheadlines.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/multiwindow.jpg))</sub>

If you are interested, here is a link to know how to do it :  [here](https://www.modaco.com/news/android/developers-add-support-for-samsung-multi-window-to-your-apps-r823)

My problem is that I need to know the height/width that my app uses.
I'm doing this :

```
displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
heightScreen = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
widthScreen = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
```

But this returns the size of the entire screen, not just the part that my app uses. My activity is  only compose by a Panel which take the entire space, but the panel.getHeight() or getWidth() return 0.

How can I get the real height/width ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My activity is only compose by a Panel which take the entire space, but the panel.getHeight() or getWidth() return 0.

Try checking later. You are probably checking for this in `onCreate()`, which is too soon AFAIK.

Comment: Yeah, you were right. I now do it in the onDraw method and it's cool. When the user resize the window I can be aware of.

Comment: Stephane - can you show us exactly how your solution looks at the end please?

Comment: The widgets are not actually 'drawn' and capable of reporting their sizes until the method `public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus)` is called.  You can override it and get metrics there as well (for future googlers looking for a solution).

Comment: I wonder if this going to be the way of doing things on Android N, or will Android get methods that tell us the window size at onCreate time.

Comment: @StephaneMathis What is the final solution please?